# task? service? what to async upload in android

Tags: android

I need to write a background process that read from the gps and send to a remote server.
  I found sveral classes, service, async task. Which is the best solution to use to realize a task that works even I close the app?

Answer (score 0):

Close app? If you killed the process, noone will stay alive.

Comment: I mean I can switch to other apps while running

Comment: I think that better to use Service. As for me, AsyncTasks are good for simple API calls, in Service you could have more functionality. Also Service has high priority, so it will be killed by process in the last order.

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask` is attached to the Process(Main Thread) , basically a background thread spawned from the main thread. But that being said the `onPostExecute()` is run on the main UI thread while the `doInBackground()` runs in a background thread so it will run until its done or if the JVM process is killed to free memory. Generally `AsyncTask` are used for small network operations.

In your case i would suggest to use a `Service` if you want some long running background task or something which you need to run even if the app is not being used by the user.

This should be a good start for you : https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html